# How to put a pic floating on the text? Like the star on the file

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]How to put a pic floating on the text? Like the star on the bottom

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `eso-pic` to put things on the background and `tikz` to draw the shape and put it any position (using `overlay`). There are many additional things you could do or use, including `tikz-pagenodes` for having access to the text area and many other things. (If you use `\AddToShipoutPictureBG{` instead of `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{`, the star will be on every page.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [star, star point height=.5cm, minimum size=2cm, fill=red!20,
        anchor=south east]  at ([xshift=-5cm,yshift=5cm]current page.south east)    {};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\foreach \X in {1,...,50} {\noindent ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `tikzmark` you can anchor the shape at some specific mark (or `\tikzmarknode`) that you add to the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,tikzmark}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [star, star point height=.5cm, minimum size=2cm, fill=red!20,
        anchor=south east]  at (pic cs:m37) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\foreach \X in {1,...,50} 
{\noindent ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV\tikzmark{m\X}\par}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but, what can I do if I want to use a pic I draw by myself?

Comment: @LiamChang What do you mean by " I draw by myself"? If you have a graphics, you can use `\node  at ([xshift=-5cm,yshift=5cm]current page.south east)    {\includegraphics{<filename>};` instead of the star.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos), which easily place graphic boxes on the page, also with text overlaying the graphics.

If you prefer to have the graphic on each page, use can place the macro in the running header.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern, lipsum, microtype, graphicx}

%% Logo 12 mm - Plasseres 62 mm fra høyre, 10 mm fra topp
%% \BRGLogo plasseres rett etter \begin{document}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\Logo}{%
  \begin{textblock}{12}(144,200)
      \includegraphics*[height=20mm]{c:/temp/homer-simpson.png}%
  \end{textblock}%
  }

\begin{document}
\Logo
\section{start}
\lipsum[2-8]

\end{document}
```